# Easy, compatible 2d/ maybe 3d animation software

Tags: animation, 2d

I'm am currently learning game development with C++ and OpenGL/SDL although I am not a fan of spending most of my time trying to make decent looking animations/models. 
My sister is also only 12, very much enjoys drawing, dislikes math, and is in love with anime shows..... So I was wondering:

**Whats are all of your suggestions on some simple 2d animation / model designing programs that don't require much math or experience we could learn together?**

We both would very much appreciate any book / online tutorial suggestions also on how to actually use the software! It would also be great if the file's format could be compatible or easily convertible to ones I could use in my games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question maybe does not belongs here...

But I would say [Blender(3d animation)](http://www.blender.org/), [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/), [Maya](http://usa.autodesk.com/maya/) etc... are good programs, so review them, for example blender is free but is not very friendly, flash costs some money....

Answer (score 0):

There are many software that you can buy. Some are subscription Based and Some are one-time price model.

I suggest you to buy a software that is not subscription base.

You can check…

Doodle Maker
https://linktr.ee/DoodleMaker

Animation Studio
https://linktr.ee/Animationstudio2

CreateStudio
https://linktr.ee/aliraza112 (2d + 3d My Favorite)